# In sqlite3 select max, min function can not get the correct results

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( 
    timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    channel   INTEGER  DEFAULT '0',
    raw_Value REAL     DEFAULT '0',
    modify    REAL     DEFAULT '0' 
);
```

I can get correct results with this query

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT TIMESTAMP
      WHERE value=
      (SELECT max(value))) AS maxDate
FROM
      (SELECT *,raw_value AS value
         FROM DATA
         WHERE TIMESTAMP>='2017-01-23 00:00:00'
         AND TIMESTAMP<'2017-01-24 00:00:00'
         AND channel=0);
```

The result is:

```
maxDate
-------------------
2017-01-23 16:47:00
```

but when I use this query, then I have a (null) result

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP
     WHERE value=
     (SELECT max(value))) AS maxDate,

  (SELECT TIMESTAMP
     WHERE value=
     (SELECT min(value))) AS minDate
FROM
  (SELECT *,raw_value AS value
     FROM DATA
   WHERE TIMESTAMP>='2017-01-23 00:00:00'
   AND TIMESTAMP<'2017-01-24 00:00:00'
   AND channel=0);
```

The result is:

```
maxDate     minDate
----------  -------------------
            2017-01-23 12:32:00
```

when I use this query,just changed order：

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP
     WHERE value=
     (SELECT min(value))) AS minDate，

  (SELECT TIMESTAMP
     WHERE value=
     (SELECT max(value))) AS maxDate


FROM
  (SELECT *,raw_value AS value
     FROM DATA
   WHERE TIMESTAMP>='2017-01-23 00:00:00'
   AND TIMESTAMP<'2017-01-24 00:00:00'
   AND channel=0);
```

now i get this:

```
minDate     maxDate
----------  -------------------
            2017-01-23 16:47:00
```

do I miss something?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I plan to get the max  and min value time of occurrence

Answer (score 0):

How about just a join and `group by`:

```
SELECT t.timestamp, t.value
FROM (SELECT value, MIN(TIMESTAMP) as min_timestamp, MAX(TIMESTAMP) as max_TIMESTAMP
      FROM DATA
      WHERE TIMESTAMP >= '2017-01-23 00:00:00' AND
            TIMESTAMP < '2017-01-24 00:00:00' AND
            channel = 0
     ) tt JOIN
     DATA t
     ON t.TIMESTAMP IN (min_timestamp, max_timestamp)
WHERE t.channel = 0;
```